# Modern alternatives to packaging and deploying enterprise applications?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, packaging

What are the modern alternatives to package and deploy server side java software<sup>1)</sup> in heterogeneous environments<sup>2)</sup> ?

I could not find a lot of coherent or up to date information on the topic but I have a few ideas. I'll start

1. The traditional application server approach ([Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), etc.)

   - Assemble software into `war` files and craft your own provisioning and deployment script, e.g., using [izpack](http://izpack.org/), [ant scripts](https://ant.apache.org/), [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) or something similar.
2. Rely on integration platforms, e.g., [fabric8](http://fabric8.io/), [servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/), [fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/overview/), etc.

   - Seems like a nice opinionated approach. If not already using one of these, apart from a lock-in, re-rolling an application into this format requires a bit of work. Isn't the trend to move away from large frameworks?
3. Bundle application `war` files into `ear` (Enterprise archives) files

   - Requires a full-fledged java EE server, e.g., [wildfly](http://wildfly.org/), [glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/) etc. Unless the capabilities of such server is needed it adds a lot of overhead to what a zip-archive could do already.
4. Virtual machines: [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), etc.

   - Docker is nice but on a windows host needs to be run in a VM anyway. VMs (vagrant or not) incurs a performance overhead and tends to rely on complex provisioning tools such as [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/).
5. Runnable jars, e.g., [Capsule](https://github.com/puniverse/capsule), [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/).

   - [Capsule](https://github.com/puniverse/capsule) seems great, it's like an executable, self-extracting zip file, which also runs the application. With an embedded jetty multiple traditional `war` files can be served from one executable.

The first option has been my reference approach for long but requires a lot of provisioning, install scripts, both which varies on different environments (e.g., Linux, Windows).

What modern alternatives are out there that makes packaging and deployment easier?

<sup>1) Picture a SOA like setup with microservices, RESTful communication etc.</sup> 
<sup>2) With that in mind let's rule out `PaaS` providers such as cloudbees, cloudfoundy etc. They deserve a topic of their own.</sup>

Comment: great question, I will share our way of handling this problem soon

Comment: now can't add it its blocked, but we are doing something cool around it, I will like to share feel free to reach out

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'll try to reformulate the question to get it open again in a few days

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I Tried to reword the question into a problem and asking for a better way to overcome it. Eligigble for reopening or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend reading [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/) document, inspired by *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture* and *Refactoring* books by Martin Fowler. It suggests the following:

1. There should be one [codebase](http://12factor.net/codebase) (version control system) per app, and many deploys of the app in different environments (development, staging, production).
2. [Dependencies](http://12factor.net/dependencies) should be explicitly declared and isolated (never relying on the implicit existence of system-wide packages or system tools).
3. [Config](http://12factor.net/config) (everything that is likely to vary between deploys) should be stored in the environment, never in the code.
4. [Backing services](http://12factor.net/backing-services) (including other apps) should be treated as attached resources, accessed via locators/credentials stored in the [config](http://12factor.net/config).
5. [Build, release and run](http://12factor.net/build-release-run) stages should be strictly separated from each other.
6. The app should be executed as one or more stateless and share-nothing [processes](http://12factor.net/processes) (state should never be stored in "sticky sessions", but in  a datastore that offers time-expiration).
7. The app should be completely self-contained (typically adding a webserver library to the app), exporting HTTP as a service by [port binding](http://12factor.net/port-binding).
8. Due to the partitionable nature of the twelve-factor app [processes](http://12factor.net/processes), adding more [concurrency](http://12factor.net/concurrency) should be simply and reliably achieved via the process model.
9. The app should treat [disposability](http://12factor.net/disposability) by achieving fast startup and graceful shutdown.
10. Development, staging, and production environments should be as similar as possible ([Dev/prod parity](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity)).
11. The app should treat [logs](http://12factor.net/logs) as event streams, never concerning with its routing or storage.
12. [Admin processes](http://12factor.net/admin-processes) should run as one-off processes.

There's also the article on [Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) by James Lewis and Martin Fowler, that states some of the ideas enumerated above.

Regarding packaging and deploying, the latter article recommendations are:

1. [Componentization via Services](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#ComponentizationViaServices)

   Apps (and their microservices) should be implemented as out-of-process components (rather than in-process libraries) that can be independently replaced, upgraded, and deployed. Components provide a more explicit component interface by using explicit remote call mechanisms.
2. [Organized around Business Capabilities](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#OrganizedAroundBusinessCapabilities)

   Each component should be organized around business capability, for a specific business area, taking a road-stack implementation of software including user-interface, persistent storage, and any external collaborations. This approach also allows a cross-team project to work together on the same component (and own the product over its full lifetime).
3. [Smart endpoints and dumb pipes](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#SmartEndpointsAndDumbPipes)

   Apps built from microservices should be choreographed using simple RESTish protocols. The two most commonly used protocols are HTTP request-response with resource API's, and lightweight messaging over a dumb bus (such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)).
4. [Infrastructure Automation](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#InfrastructureAutomation)

   The operational complexity of building, deploying and operating microservices can be reduced by automation with [Continuous Delivery](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContinuousDelivery.html) or it's precursor, [Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, the Tomcat Maven Plugin has a goal that will create an executable JAR along with the standard WAR. You can the run the jar using java -jar path_to.jar. Kind of a fun way to run an app without a preexisting Tomcat installation. Check it out: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html

Comment: This approach is restricted to web applications. Good to know about that, anyway. Thanks :-)